# not able to pull image in POD ,getting ImagePullBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have my kubernetes nodes on different vms . each VM has 1 kubernetes node . in total I have 7 worker nodes

While trying to create POD on 1 node I get ImagepullBackOff error while docker pull on the same node is successful .
rest of the worker nodes are working fine
My docker registry is already set as insecure-regiry in daemon.json

pls help

Answer (score 0):

`ImagePullBackOff` is almost always a typo in the image name. Make sure you specified the name correctly.

Comment: POD is being created using yml file and rest of the nodes are able to pull the same image from yml file . I am getting the problem with 2 of my worker nodes while the rest 5 are ok .

Comment: Can you verify that your malfunctioning nodes have working DNS and internet connectivity?

Comment: not sure what to check for that

Comment: exec into the pod and ping `google.com`.
`kubectl exec -ti <podname> ping google.com`

Comment: not able to get inside the pod which has ImagePullBack  . getting 
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("container-Name")

Comment: can you please share the pod YAML?

Comment: added yaml file in question. docker pull on the same worked node is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to describe the Pod using: `kubectl describe pod <name>`. It will show a more detailed message why pulling fails.

Answer (score 0):

The kubernetes service account attached to the Pod is probably not able to pull the image. The service account must have the correct ImagePullSecrets.

When no service account is configured, it uses the `default` service account.

```
kubectl get sa -o yaml
```

This will give a list of ImagePullSecrets attached to this service account. See if you have created the correct secret and attached it to the service account.

Answer (score 0):

resolved the issue.
issue was the Container runtime. affected nodes were using containrd as runtime and I setup these nodes to access my insecure registry for containerd . everything was OK after that.